# JBoss JMS provider

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, jms, jboss-tools

I need to write a Message Driven Bean. I'm using JBoss IDE 1.5. I understand the concept behind MDB's but I don't really know how to install the JMS provider (JBoss MQ? I think) and use it so that it will be used to broker my message to an MDB.

does anyone know of a tutorial I can use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JBossMQ](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/jbossmq) is the default JMS provider in JBoss 3.2.x and 4.x but is replaced by [JBoss Messaging](http://www.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/)<sup>1</sup> in JBoss AS 5.0 (JBoss Messaging 1.x is the default JMS provider in JBoss AS version 5).

Depending on the version of JBoss you are using, you already have a JMS provider so I'm not sure what you want to install. And for the configuration part (e.g. how to create a Queue/Topic to which you could send messages), you have to provide some XML files.

- Check the Configuration section of http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/jbossmq and especially the [Destinations](http://www.jboss.org/community/docs/DOC-9336) page for JBossMQ. This [blog post](http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2006/08/how-to-create-queuetopic-in-jboss.html) might help too.
- Check the chapter [6.6 Configuring Destinations](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossmessaging/freezone/docs/userguide-1.4.4.GA/html/configuration.html#conf.destination) of the [Jboss Messaging 1.4 user guide](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossmessaging/freezone/docs/userguide-1.4.4.GA/html/index.html). This [blog post](http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2009/06/05/configuring-jms-in-jboss-5/) might help.

Note that starting with JBoss AS version 5.1.0, there is an admin console that allows to create *JMS Destinations* (expand the "JMS Destinations" entry in the tree view, click on either Queues or Topics, and the in the right panel click the "Add a new resource" button) and/or *Connection Factories*.

---

<sup>1</sup>Starting from version 2.0, JBoss Messaging has been rebranded to [HornetQ](http://jboss.org/hornetq/).