# How to find JMS version used in an application?

Tags: jboss, jms, version

I have an application which uses [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) api. The Application server used is jboss-5.0.0.CR2. Is there any way to get the version of JMS used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to distinguish between JMS version 1.1 and 2.0.

- JMS 2.0 API consists of three new interfaces: JMSContext,
  JMSProducer, and JMSConsumer
- JMSContext replaces the separate Connection and Session objects in 
  in version 1.1 with a single object.
- JMSProducer replaces MessageProducer object in version 1.1
- JMSConsumer replaces the MessageConsumer object in version 1.1

More details:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jms20-1947669.html

Comment: Differentiating 2.0 and 1.1 is a no brainer since JMS 2.0 is only supported by Java EE 7 compliant containers. One need not look at so many details.

Answer (score 0):

jboss-5.0.0.CR2 is the application server version - not the JMS provider. From what I know, HornetQ is the JMS implementation which JBoss uses. Anyway, since JBoss 5 is Java EE 5 compliant, the JMS API version has to be 1.0. Java EE 6 aligns with JMS 1.1 and Java EE 7 has the latest JMS specification version i.e. 2.0

Comment: I have corrected that. However I found that JBoss Messaging is the JMS provider used in JBoss AS 5.0 Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658388/jboss-jms-provider

Comment: Probably. But that doesn't matter. The JMS API version would continue to be 1.0 irrespective of the actual provider

Comment: JMS 2.0 was released in April 2013 and is a part of the Java EE 7 platform. Version 1.1 was used in Java EE 5 & 6

Comment: :-) I think I already mentioned that in my answer (before). Java EE 5 is compliant with JMS 1.1 - you are right about that. J2EE 1.4 and before were aligned with JMS 1.0. Java EE 5 bought in a maintenance release on top of 1.0

Comment: yes Abhishek,Thanks! I was just making it more clear. I was in search of how to distinguish between 1.1 and 2.0 code as both versions can be used in JEE 7. As you said as I was using JBoss 5.X my code is definitely JMS ver 1.1